# Nginx configuration changes from java code

Tags: java, file-io, nginx

How do i convert Nginx configuration file to a java objects. Is there any libraries to do that.

**Objective**

I have to update and add different configuration settings to the Nginx config file from java code. Is there easy way to do that if not converting to java objects and writing them back to the file?

**Tried**

I am trying to identify the pattern in the file. And then i am reading each and every line to create respective objects. Am i following right approach?

Answer (score 3):

Cheers: https://github.com/odiszapc/nginx-java-parser

However, as stated, this *may* or *may not* have some issue, but still
looks quite fine for what you're asking for.

Comment: I am able to write to the configuration file. I know i have to use AST tree objects and modify it and write back. But how should i do it. :  Please Help!!